# Can secrets be set for Cloud Function via Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

The Terraform `google_cloudfunctions_function` resource documentation lists [secret environment variables](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function#secret_environment_variables) as an optional argument. I'm either not using it correctly or, contrary to the documentation, it's not in fact supported.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = var.function_name
  runtime     = "nodejs16"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.zip.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = var.function_entry_point

  secret_environment_variables = []
}
```

results in:

> Error: Unsupported argument on modules/cloud-function/main.tf
> line 51, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function":
> 51:   secret_environment_variables = {} An argument named
> "secret_environment_variables" is not expected here. Did you mean to
> define a block of type "secret_environment_variables"?

This is the result of `terraform version`:

```
Terraform v1.1.9
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external v2.2.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.18.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, that key should be block. Here is an example:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = var.function_name
  runtime     = "nodejs16"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.zip.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = var.function_entry_point

  secret_environment_variables {
    key = "myvar"
    secret = "mysecret_id"
  }
}
```

Comment: a side question - is it possible to have more than one 'secret environment variables'?

Comment: according to documentation and this code line: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/36dde45efcd9ae02d52c1c23539f601805087f9a/google/resource_cloudfunctions_function.go#L343 - the 'version' attribute might be mandatory.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to put a secret in plain text in terraform files?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The secret is an id, referencing a value stored in GCP Secret Manager

Comment: @al-dann Yes, you should be able to specify multiple `secret_environment_variables` blocks. Generally any attribute in block form is that way so that it can be specified more than once.

Comment: The `secret` value is the *ID of the secret in secret manager* not the secret itself