# Can secrets be provided for Google Cloud function gen 2 using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

For gen 1 google cloud functions there's a possibility of providing secrets, described, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71969558/can-secrets-be-set-for-cloud-function-via-terraform):

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = var.function_name
  runtime     = "nodejs16"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.zip.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = var.function_entry_point

  secret_environment_variables {
    key = "myvar"
    secret = "mysecret_id"
  }
}
```

Since in gen 2 the structure of resource is a bit different (see below), is there a possibility of providing secrets to the gen 2 cloud function inside `main.tf` file?

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  name = "function"
  location = "us-central1"
  description = "a new function"

  build_config {
    runtime = "nodejs16"
    entry_point = "helloPubSub"  # Set the entry point 
    environment_variables = {
        BUILD_CONFIG_TEST = "build_test"
    }
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.object.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count  = 3
    min_instance_count = 1
    available_memory    = "256M"
    timeout_seconds     = 60
    environment_variables = {
        SERVICE_CONFIG_TEST = "config_test"
    }
    ingress_settings = "ALLOW_INTERNAL_ONLY"
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = true
    service_account_email = google_service_account.account.email
  }

  event_trigger {
    trigger_region = "us-central1"
    event_type = "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished"
    pubsub_topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic.id
    retry_policy = "RETRY_POLICY_RETRY"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `secret_environment_variables` in `service_config` like this:

```
service_config {
  ...
  timeout_seconds     = 60
  secret_environment_variables = {
    key = "myvar"
    secret = "mysecret_id"
  }
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function#example-usage---cloudfunctions2-secret-env) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to add more than 1 secret variable?

Comment: @gamble27 you should be able to specify the same block again with different values.